# How do I get this nested type in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export declare type ReceiptEnum = {
    Action: {
        actions: Action[]; // Action is a type too. Consider it as a string for the ex.
        gasPrice: string;
        inputDataIds: string[];
        outputDataReceivers: string[];
        signerId: string;
        signerPublicKey: string;
    };
} | {
    Data: {
        data: string;
        dataId: string;
    };
};
```

I have this above code and I want to cast something which will be of type

```
const data : ReceiptEnum['Action'] = {}; // This doesn't work
```

How would I do that in TS? Doing this currentlt throws an error `Property 'Action' does not exist on type 'ReceiptEnum'`

Comment: What exactly is `ReceiptEnum.Action.actions`s type? The code you have provided actually has two errors. `Action` is not a known type.

Comment: Fair question. My bad. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: "*It throws an error `Property 'Action' does not exist on type 'ReceiptEnum'`*" - a better, more precise error message would have been "Property 'Action' does not exist on **all variants of** type 'ReceiptEnum'". See [this simplified example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMoF4oDeAUFFANYQgBcUARAIYDGwacGAKutrQNwlRMWbGgQC+fUVAA+hfhWp0AJvWD1OmLL37LVI8UX1FQkKAGlKeWImRcsAbQDk8hwF0eUAPQeoAdzgAnMgBnI3BoAEFmVgwANXoAGwBXaHx4JFQNR0Fo13cvKAAzejR4oKA).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot refer to a property of a union like that. You will need to declare separate types for them:

```
interface ReceiptAction {
    actions: Action[];
    gasPrice: string;
    inputDataIds: string[];
    outputDataReceivers: string[];
    signerId: string;
    signerPublicKey: string;
}
interface ReceiptData {
    data: string;
    dataId: string;
}    
export declare type ReceiptEnum = {
    Action: ReceiptAction
} | {
    Data: ReceiptAction;
};
```

Then you can directly refer to just `ReceiptAction`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, Just wanted to make sure there was no other way! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<s>TypeScript does, as far as I'm concerned, not support enums containing struct like data (unlike rust, for example) which seems you are trying to recreate here.</s> ***See the comments***

You can't index the type like that. TypeScript does not *have<sub>1</sub>* any information about the union variants until you check which one it is. That's why you can't index it. And even if you could, the resulting type would not be assignable to `ReceiptEnum`.

But you may still construct your existing type the following way:

```js
const data: ReceiptEnum = {
    Action: {
        gasPrice: "",
        inputDataIds: [],
        outputDataReceivers: [],
        signerId: "",
        signerPublicKey: "",
    },
};
```

But I normally use a separate field (e.g. `type`) to distinguish union variants. It's a pretty common pattern in TypeScript to the extent of my knowledge.

```js
export enum ReceiptType {
    Action,
    Data,
}

export interface ActionReceipt {
    type: ReceiptType.Action,
    actions: Action[];
    gasPrice: string;
    inputDataIds: string[];
    outputDataReceivers: string[];
    signerId: string;
    signerPublicKey: string;
}

export interface DataReceipt {
    type: ReceiptType.Data,
    data: string;
    dataId: string;
}

export type Receipt = ActionReceipt | DataReceipt;

// Usage:

const receipt: Receipt = {
    type: ReceiptType.Action,
    actions: [],
    gasPrice: "",
    inputDataIds: [],
    outputDataReceivers: [],
    signerId: "",
    signerPublicKey: "",
};

processReceipt(receipt);

function processReceipt(receipt: Receipt) {
    if (receipt.type == ReceiptType.Action) {
        return processActionReceipt(receipt);
    }

    throw new Error(`processing of receipt type ${receipt.type} not implemented`);
}

function processActionReceipt(receipt: ActionReceipt) {}
```

- <sub>1</sub> TypeScript obviously has some information about the union variants. For example, if they share a common property, you can use that. This is also how my suggestion works.

Comment: "*TypeScript does, as far as I'm concerned, not support enums containing struct like data*" - it does, it just doesn't provide a way to refer to the individual variants or their properties, unless the property exists on all variants (as is common for a discriminator). See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMoF4oDeAUFFANYQgBcUARAIYDGwacGAKutrQNwlRMWbGgQC+fUVAA+hfhWp0AJvWD1OmLL37LVI8UX1FQkKAGlKeWImRcsAbQDk8hwF0eUAPQeoAdzgAnMgBnI3BoAEFmVgwANXoAGwBXaHx4JFQNR0Fo13cvKAAzejR4oKA).

Answer (score 0):

Well it makes a lot of sense that TS is throwing that error at you. You're declaring that `data` is of type `Action` despite `Action` having a number of mandatory fields`that don't exist in the empty object that is assigned to`data`.

If the goal here is to pretend that `data` is already a valid `Action` type then what we want to do is something like this:

```js
const data = {} as ReceiptEnum['Action'];
```

What I recommend you do instead of this though is have all of the fields ready to go ahead of time and then create the `Action` without pretending as if `data` already contains the fields that we expect it to contain. So maybe something like this instead:

```js
const actions = alreadyPreparedActions;
const gasPrice = '$5.00';
const inputDataIds = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const outputDataReceivers = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
const signerId = 'super signer!';
const signerPublicKey = 'ghi';

const data: ReceiptEnum['Action'] = {
    actions,
    gasPrice,
    inputDataIds,
    outputDataReceivers,
    signerId,
    signerPublicKey,
};
```

Comment: Ah okay, So I tried the above thing and what you say makes sense.
But
`const data = {} as ReceiptEnum['Action'];` this again throws the same error. It says It cannot find a property of type 'Action` in the `ReceiptEnum` type

Comment: Maybe you need `as Partial<ReceiptEnum['Action']>`